# How to decompose one large object conditional on columns with a string and a column containing numerics?

Tags: r

I have a very large object containing a matrix with countries, sectors and years. For illustrative purposes I create a matrix a, which is similar in structure to the real thing:

```
a <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

countries <- c("UK", "USA", "UK", "USA")
rownames(a) <- countries

sector <- c("UK1", "UK2", "USA1", "USA2")
colnames(a) <- sector

year <- c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001)

a <- cbind(year, a)
```

Giving the matrix:

```
    year UK1 UK2 USA1 USA2
UK  2000   1   2    3    4
USA 2000   5   6    7    8
UK  2001   9  10   11   12
USA 2001  13  14   15   16
```

In this example, I want to create matrices "UK" and "USA" that contain elements of their own sectors (which are defined by the country name and a numeric) and ignore all the rest, and do so for each year.

It would be possible to do this here by cutting every other row and column like so:

```
UK <- a[-c(2, 4), -c(4, 5)]
USA <- a[-c(1, 3), -c(2, 3)]
```

Giving UK:

```
   year UK1 UK2
UK 2000   1   2
UK 2001   9  10
```

and the US:

```
    year USA1 USA2
USA 2000    7    8
USA 2001   15   16
```

But this is really not possible for my large data set. Is there a code that matches countries with with the strings of the column names? i.e. USA with USA1 and USA2, and then repeat for every year?

Comment: Something like this maybe? `var = "UK";

a[grepl(var, row.names(a)) ,
  grepl(var, colnames(a))]`

Comment: It seems to work, but how can I store the results in an object? When I run the code I get an object "var" which returns "UK"

Comment: You have to save the other table object as well, like `tbl = a[...]`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses `grepl` on the row and column names of the matrix to identify which rows/columns we want to retain for a given country.  Note that in all cases we want to retain the `year` column.

```
country <- "UK"
cols <- grepl(paste0(country, "|year"), colnames(a))
rows <- grepl(country, rownames(a))

a[rows, cols]
   year UK1 UK2
UK 2000   1   2
UK 2001   9  10
```

### Demo

Comment: I think it has to do with selecting positions of rows rather than selecting rows `c("UK","UK")`. I.e. duplicate row name...

Comment: @AntoniosK You're right...it happened to work with the columns because the names were all unique, but not with the rows, where `UK` appeared more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the tidyverse. First we create a narrow format tidy data set, and then we use a function to extract country specific rows and columns.

```
a <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
country <- c("UK", "USA", "UK", "USA")
sector <- c("UK1", "UK2", "USA1", "USA2")
colnames(a) <- sector
year <- c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001)

library(tidyr)
data.frame(cbind(country,year, a)) %>% 
     gather(.,key="sector",value="value",UK1:USA2) -> tidyA

# create matrix of country
countryMatrix <- function(df,country){
     df[df$country == country & grepl(country,df$sector)== TRUE,] %>%
     spread(.,key=sector,value)
}
countryMatrix(tidyA,"USA")
countryMatrix(tidyA,"UK")
```

...and the output:

```
> countryMatrix(tidyA,"USA")
  country year USA1 USA2
1     USA 2000    7    8
2     USA 2001   15   16
> countryMatrix(tidyA,"UK")
  country year UK1 UK2
1      UK 2000   1   2
2      UK 2001   9  10
>
```